# make available a click function only in a if condition

Tags: jquery, function, click

Hello I have a feature that makes me the click function, and so far so good

```
   $('.punta').click(function() { 
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/clickButton",
                data: "value=" + value,
                dataType: "html" 
            });
        });
```

now what I would do is make it available only if certain controls are successful
to give a practical example

```
$(".punta").hover(
        function () {
            if(qualcosa){
//MAKE AVAILABLE THE CLICK OF FUNCTION BEFORE
}
        }, 
        function () {
blabla
        }
        );
```

here is a thing I would do,
I tried to give a name to the function (the first) tip

```
function provaclick(){
  $('.punta').click(function() { 
bla bla
```

and then put the name of the function inside the if statement, but I do not know why clicking ONCE, and as if I click 3 or 4 times (I have seen on firebug)
so I think I should declare the function in another way such

$. function na thing but I just can not fix

someone can give me a hand? thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear can you put that on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change elements css classes for achieving that...